# How to add custom classes to react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I want to be able to add a custom class to a block or selected text. How do I do that?

1. I didn't find a way to add any custom block types.
2. When adding custom toolbar buttons, I didn't find a way to insert html, only plain text.

Comment: just read and follow draftjs official document